# Is YOLO model using a validation set for pure training purpose?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

For what concerns training, validation and test dataset I think there is a little bit of confusion in literature terminology.

I'm using this repo to train a model on custom 9 classes: https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov3
I don't understand if here the validation set is used in the training process (i.e. tune hyperparameters, etc..) or is used only to calculate some metrics (so as a "test" set of UNSEEN data).

Could anyone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Just to say that there is indeed some confusion about this, but to my knowledge it's more common to use "validation set" for a subset of the training data used during training, and "test set" for the unseen instances used for evaluation.